# Notation for the set of the subgroups of a group?

Tags: group-theory, notation, terminology

Given a group $G$, is there a "standard notation" to denote the set of the subgroups of $G$?

Comment: There is no standard notation. Why do you need one? Words are probably better. If you do need a notation, just say it explicitly.

Comment: I'd be interested to hear if there is one, like how $\mathcal{P}(A)$ denotes the set of subsets of $A$.  If there isn't a special notation, you could still define it to be $\{H~:~H\leq G\}$ (where here $\leq$ means '*is a subgroup of*')

Comment: In fact, I do not need one as I you said I can use words. However, as $H \le G$ denotes a subgroup, I was curious to understand if there was a standard notation for the set of subgroups.

Comment: @lhf, words are certainly *not* better! It is the year 2015, and our functions deserve explicit codomains!

Comment: @goblin being extremely set theoretically precise is more of an early 20th century thing (maybe also a set theorist thing). If anything, at least in my field, words are preferred over a sea of nonstandard notation when they're clear.

Comment: @MattSamuel, note that codomains weren't even *around* in the early 20th century.

Comment: @goblin the modern definition was around in 1925 and was standard in 1939.

Comment: @MattSamuel, do you have a reference for this? I have seen it written that Bourbaki introduced codomains for the first time in their 1939 Set Theory text.

Comment: @goblin I found it on the history of functions on Wikipedia. The ordered pair definition is of unknown origin but was used by Von Neumann in 1925. Things are rarely introduced for the first time in a textbook.

Comment: @MattSamuel, interesting. So it seems that Russell toyed with the idea of codomains (called "relatums"). I'm not sure if he actually ended up using them though. In any event, I still don't think its correct to say that this is an early 20th century idea. Even Bourbaki's 1939 text didn't really do them properly, for the simple reason that [material set theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/material+set+theory) is not the right context for codomains...

Comment: ...  Imo, their importance only becomes clear once you start doing category theory and [structural set theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/structural+set+theory). This explains why no modern set theorist uses codomains in their formalization of mathematics inside ZFC. Ergo, I rend to regard codomains as a post-1945 idea, when Eilenberg and MacLane's "general theory of natural equivalences" was published. Before category theory, codomains were just this weird oddity that certain very odd professors would occasionally include in (mostly very esoteric) works that bordered on philosophy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I know of.

Some suggestions:

1. $\mathrm{Sub}_{\mathbf{Grp}}G$ or $\mathrm{Sub}(G)$
2. $\mathrm{S}_{\mathbf{Grp}}G$ or $\mathrm{S}(G)$

Notation 1 is used [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/subobject#the_poset_of_subobjects).

Comment: Maybe you're at the start of new math notation... Great!

Comment: In my paper with Guyot and Pitsch on subgroups of abelian groups (http://www.normalesup.org/~cornulier/CGPab.pdf), we used $\mathcal{S}(G)$. In various papers on "invariant random subgroups" (IRS) they use $\mathrm{Sub}(G)$ or $\mathrm{Sub}_G$. Sometimes $\mathcal{C}(G)$ has been used, $\mathcal{C}$ referring to Chabauty (who introduced a natural topology on the set of *closed* subgroups when $G$ is locally compact). I also saw $\mathfrak{L}(G)$ in old Russian texts (possibly L stands for lattice?).

Answer (score 2):

In my textbook (Abstract Algebra - A comprehensive treatment, by F. van Oystaeyen, C. Menini), $ \mathcal{L}(G) $ is used, although they do not give a specific name for it, although they even go further. While 
$$ \mathcal{L}(G) = \{K \mid K \leq G\} $$
they even introduce
$$ \mathcal{L}(G; S) = \{K \subseteq S \mid K \leq G\}, $$ where $ S $ is a subset of $G$.

I wonder if this thing even has a name, in the same way that $\mathcal{P}(X) $ is called “Power set of X”.

Comment: Is it the lattice of subgroups?